# How we can pass the graph type dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to pass the graph type dynamically by selecting the options from the select list. Below is my code :

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select id="ChartType" name="ChartType" onchange="drawChart()">
      <option value = "0">Select Chart Type
      <option value="PieChart">PieChart
      <option value="Histogram">Histogram
      <option value="LineChart">LineChart
      <option value="BarChart">BarChart
    </select>
    <div id="chart_div" style="border: solid 2px #000000;" ></div>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <p id="demo1"></p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
    // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
    // draws it.      
    function drawChart() {
        // Create the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');    
        data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
        data.addRows([
          ['Mushrooms', 3],
          ['Onions', 4],
          ['Olives', 1],
          ['Zucchini', 5],
          ['Pepperoni', 2]
        ]);         
        var a = document.getElementById("ChartType").value;
        document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "You selected: " + a;  
        // Set chart options
        var options = {
            'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
            'width':400,
            'height':300
        };             
        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        //passing the value which I am reading after selecting the options from the select.
        var chart = new google.visualization.document.getElementById("ChartType").value(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

However I am unable to get the graph. I am trying to select the option as Histogram and I want the graph to be Histogram and if I am selecting Pie-Chart the graph should be Pie-Chart with the same value.

Comment: This works... https://jsfiddle.net/Ltxmz9h8/1/ I don't get where exactly your problem is... can you try to break it down to a minimal working example?

Comment: or like this https://jsfiddle.net/Ltxmz9h8/2/ if you want the `onchange` attribute in your html instead of adding the event listener by script.

Comment: Hi Simon, What I need here is my graph will change as I select different graph type from the select list. e.g: If I have selected the option as Line-Chart then a Line-chart graph should be appear. If I have selected Pie-Chart then a Pie-Chart graph should appear not the Line-Chart.

Comment: Press `F12` to open the developer tools, and refresh your page. Do you get any errors?

Comment: Yes cdrini. I am getting an error stating that "Uncaught Type Error: Cannot read property 'getElementById' of undefined". Even I tried passing the variable a as well but of no use.

Comment: @AnubhavMishra does it give you a line number of where that error is?

Comment: @cdrini yup. line no is: 53. I am getting error in the code `var chart = new google.visualization.document.getElementById("ChartType").value(document.getElementById('chart_div'));`

Comment: @cdrini what I am trying to do here is take the value from option and pass it as chart-type. Is there other way using which I can change the chart-type

Comment: @AnubhavMishra Ah, I see the problem; answer posted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error on this line:

```
var chart = new google.visualization.document.getElementById("ChartType").value(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
```

it should be:

```
var chart = new google.visualization[document.getElementById("ChartType").value](document.getElementById('chart_div'));
```

To use a string as a key, you have to use `[]`. Here's why:

```
var a = "someProperty";
var myObject = {
  someProperty: 3,
  a: 4
};

console.log(myObject.a); // 4
console.log(myObject[a]); // 3
console.log(myObject.someProperty); // 3
console.log(myObject["someProperty"]); // 3
```

Comment: Thank you @cdrini. Now I understand whats my mistake is.